# How many integer solutions are there to this equation?

Tags: combinatorics

How many nonnegative integer solutions are there to: $x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 10$? I am able to do this when it is simply $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ but by multiplying $x_2$ by 2 has confused me.

Comment: Did you mean *integer solutions* (there are infinitely many) or perhaps *nonnegative* integer solutions?

Comment: I assume you mean either positive or non-negative integers?  Either way, given how small the values are, easiest is probably to run through the possible values of $x_2$ and work case by case.

Comment: I meant non negative integers sorry

Comment: @lulu I understand we can go case by case, but I would like to learn how to do it using combinations and permutations as it will help me in other future problems where I wouldn't be able to go case by case.

Comment: Problems with this sort of constraint can be very hard to count for large collections.  In this case, with only three variables, it is easy since, for any fixed $x_2$ the possible $(x_1,x_3)$ are determined by $x_1$, say.  I don't think there is any sort of one-size-fits-all approach to all possible linear constraints, in general.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted.

Comment: "I understand we can go case by case, but I would like to learn how to do it using combinations and permutations as it will help me in other future problems where I wouldn't be able to go case by case."  The best thing you can to go case be case and see if tthere are patterns  and things you can generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, this sort of problems must be solved pretty much case by case, but let's try to solve at least a little bit more general problem than the particular one asked, namely how many non-negative integer solutions does the equation

$$x_1 + tx_2 + x_3 = n$$

have, where $t, n\in\mathbb{N}$.

This can be done by letting $x_1$ run through $1, 2, \dots, n$ and checking how many values the variable $x_2$ can take, so that $x_1+tx_2 \leq n$. The third variable $x_3$ will then always be forced and the solution will work (this happens because the coefficient of $x_3$ is $1$, otherwise $n-x_1-tx_2$ would need to be a multiple of the coefficient of $x_3$ to get an integer solution).

Ok, so if $x_1 = j$, for $n-j-tx_2$ to remain nonnegative, we must have

$$x_2 \leq \frac{n-j}{t}$$

and $x_2$ can take the values $0, 1, \dots, \lfloor \frac{n-j}{t} \rfloor$. Therefore the number of solutions is

$$\sum_{j=0}^n \left( 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n-j}{t} \right\rfloor \right)
= \sum_{j=0}^n \left( 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{j}{t} \right\rfloor \right)
$$
$$
=n+1 + \sum_{j=0}^n \left\lfloor \frac{j}{t} \right\rfloor
$$

(Above we just flipped the sum, i.e change of index $j\to n-j$ for a nicer looking formula).

For the particular case $t=2$, we can simplify this by considering cases $n$ even and $n$ odd, splitting the sum to even and odd parts and using the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^r k= \frac{r(r+1)}{2}$ to

$$n+1 + \left \lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \right \rfloor$$

and for $n=10$ we get $36$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$x_2$ may be $0...5$.  $x_1$ may be $0.. ,10-2x_2$ and $x_3$ is fixed at $10-2x_2 - x_1$

So there are

$\sum\limits_{x_2=0}^5 \sum\limits_{x_1=0}^{10-2x_2} 1$

Which may be reindexed as

$\sum\limits_{x_2=0}^5 \sum\limits_{x_1=10; -1}^{2x_2} 1=$

$\sum\limits_{x_2=0}^5 \sum\limits_{x_1=0}^{2x_2} 1=$

$\sum\limits_{x_2=0}^5 (2x+1) = $

$6^2 = 36$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the hope for any general methods was too hastily discarded. We can use generating functions.

If $a_n$ denotes the number of solutions to

$$c_1x_1 + c_2x_2+\dots + c_kx_k = n$$
$$x_j \geq 0$$

Then the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ is given by

$$A(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z^{c_1})(1-z^{c_2})\dots(1-z^{c_k})}$$

This comes from the fact that compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts corresponds to a integer-sequence of length $k$. Now, you can use a size-function $x\mapsto c_jx$ for each class of integers $\cal{I}_j$ in the product $\cal{I}_1 \times \cal{I}_2 \dots \times \cal{I}_k$, so you have the correct equation. The generating function of the class $\cal{I}_j$ is $\frac{1}{1-z^{c_j}}$ because ${\cal{I}}_j = \text{SEQ}(\{ Z \})$ and the element $Z$ has size $c_j$.

I don't know if this actually helps, maybe you can do partial fraction expansion of $A(z)$.

By the way, notice how in the case when all $c_j=1$ this amounts to the usual compositions:

$$A(z) = \left( \frac{1}{1-z} \right)^k = (1-z)^{-k} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty {{-k}\choose{j}} (-z)^{j}$$

so $a_j = {{-k}\choose{j}} (-1)^{j} = {{k+j-1}\choose{k-1}}$.

Comment: I realized this when reading 1.17 (on page 46) of http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf There inequality constraints between the variables are considered but similarly we can adjust the coefficients in when considering how the combinatorial class in question is constructed.